# Rigid translation transformation of a Lagrangian into a total derivative

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, symmetry, field-theory, coordinate-systems

I came across this equation while studying geometry of gravity:

$$d_L \mathcal{L} = \partial_\mu(\epsilon^\mu \mathcal{L})$$

where $d_L$ stands for a local derivative in a general coordinate transform, for a coordinate change $$x^\mu \rightarrow x^\mu + \epsilon^\mu.$$ $\mathcal{L}$ is a Lagrangian in general relativity.

I tried using the chain rule for partial derivatives and don't seem to get the same answer. In practice, testing the rule for the Dirac and KG Lagrangians seems to work but I haven't been able to prove how this general rule would be valid.

Noether's theorem gives me the same result as the chain rule for differentiation:

$d_L \mathcal{L} = \partial_\mu (\epsilon^\mu \frac{\partial{\mathcal{L}}}{\partial (\partial_\mu x)})$

So while it is a total differentiation, we can see it's not the same as the one stated above.

Comment: This question isn't a part of my homework, just genuinely unsure about the way of obtaining this result.

Comment: Tip: Consider to provide definitions, context, reference, to focus potential answers.